# How to return 2 parameters after inserting to Database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to have this particular method return the accoount type (acc_type) as well as account number (accnumber)
I have written this code, but i need to return those parameters. Very new to this, kindly help.

```
app.post('/api/create-account', function (req, res) {
    var prologue = '00345';
    var digits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000) + 100000;
    var accnumber = prologue + digits;

    var firstname = req.body.firstname;
    var lastname = req.body.lastname;

    var fullname = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
    var acc_type = req.body.acc_type;

    var address = req.body.address;
    var telephone = req.body.telephone;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var birth_date = req.body.birth_date;
    var gender = req.body.gender;
    var bvn_number = req.body.bvn_number;

    dbConn.query('insert into fdsh_demobank (firstname, lastname, address, telephone, email,birth_date, gender,bvn_number, acc_type,accnumber ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [firstname, lastname, address, telephone, email, birth_date, gender, bvn_number, acc_type, accnumber], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.status(200).send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'created' });
    });
    sendConfirmationEmail(fullname, accnumber, acc_type, email);
    sendOnboardingEmail(fullname, email);
})
```

been checking out and its not giving me the adequate results.

**Edits**

I am trying to do a SELECT statement here , says I have error on my SQL Syntax. on the SELECT * from area.

Please see the code below

```
app.get('/api/get-customer/:email', function (req, res) {
    var email = req.params.email;

    dbConn.query('select * from fsdh_demobank where email is = ?', [email], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.status(200).send({ error: false, data: results[0], message: 'customer data' });
    })
})
```

Comment: *i need to return those parameters* Execute according SELECT.

Comment: Pls see Edits, I did a return Statement and i have some error, says I have error in SQL Syntax. Please see edit.

Comment: `'select * from fsdh_demobank where email is = ?'` What exactly are you trying to do here? First, `is` is redundant. Second, what is the question mark for?